# Populating dropdownlist values based on another dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this on the jsp page of another application. I need to populate values on combobox based on another combo box. I've seen several posts explaining this but can't make it to work for myself.
Here's what I tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function customChangefunction(){
        var target = window.document.getElementsByName("resultCombo");
        var src = window.document.getElementById("sampleCombo");
        var strUser = src.options[src.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(strUser);
        var colours = new Array('Black', 'White', 'Blue');
          var shapes = new Array('Square', 'Circle', 'Triangle');
        var names = new Array('John', 'David', 'Sarah');

        switch (strUser) {
                  case 'one':
                      target.options.length = 0;
                      for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
                          createOption(target, colours[i], colours[i]);
                      }
                      break;
                  case 'two':
                      target.options.length = 0; 
                  for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                      createOption(target, shapes[i], shapes[i]);
                      }
                      break;
                  case 'three':
                      target.options.length = 0;
                      for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                          createOption(target, names[i], names[i]);
                      }
                      break;
                      default:
                          target.options.length = 0;
                      break;
            }
    }
     function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
              var opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
              opt.value = value;
              opt.text = text;
              ddl.options.add(opt);
              opt.appendChild(text);
            document.getElementById(ddl).appendChild(opt);
      }
```

The above code is not working.I have to do this without using jquery. 
My actual requirement is

```
if Combo1 is India then Combo2 should show Chennai,Delhi,Mumbai
if Combo1 is USA then Combo2 should show New York,CA,etc..
```

I have one more question. Suppose that Combo2 is already having some values does this replace those with these values.I would like to do this way

Please comment on this before you mark this question as duplicate or closing it.

Comment: you may use ajax to dynamically load contents in 2nd dropdown

Comment: I guess not necessary. I need something similar to [this] (http://jsfiddle.net/e6hzj8gx/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("food").onchange = function(Event){
    var contents = document.getElementById("contents");
    contents.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i in data[this.value]){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute('value',data[this.value][i]);
        option.text = data[this.value][i];
        contents.appendChild(option);
    }
    var expect_data = Event.target.value == "Fruits" ? "Vegetables" : "Fruits";
    for(var i in data[expect_data]){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute('value',data[expect_data][i]);
        option.text = data[expect_data][i];
        contents.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give some description?

Comment: var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute('value',data[expect_data][i]);
        option.text = data[expect_data][i];
        contents.appendChild(option); This four lines are for creating option in select list.